# how to catch the click event on a specific mesh in a group

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a group of circle geometry elements which are positioned on the vertices of a icosahedron element. I want to do a click event on each individual circle element using jQuery. So how to implement jQuery click events on these elements..

Suggest me some good references for doing it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the raycasting method. The basic mechanism is something like this:
(three revision 70 and javascript vanila)

**1) Setup targets**

```
var targets = [], 
    // When defining your 3d objects, use the push method 
    // to select the meshes you want to intersect.
    // targets.push(objectMesh);
```

**2) Setup raycaster**

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(),
    mouse = new THREE.Vector2(),
    intersects;
```

**3) Intersect target**

```
searchTarget(event){
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(targets);
    if (intersects.length > 0){
         // Use the intersected objects: 
         // intersects[0] represents the foremost object that was hovered
    }
}
```

**4) Setup listener**

```
renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', searchTarget, false);
```

You could also use jQuery: `$( "#canvas" ).mousemove( searchTarget );`

Comment: Where's the click event listener?